# NullPointerException at android widget ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

```
private void fillArrayAdapter() {
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM quotes", null);
        int count = c.getCount();
        int column = c.getColumnCount();
        Log.d("countcl", column + "");
        totalRec = new String[count * column];
        Log.d("counttot", totalRec + "");
        int i = 0;
        c.moveToFirst();
        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            totalRec[i++] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("qoutemsg"));
            c.moveToNext();
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getBaseContext(), R.layout.activity_customview, R.id.tv,
                totalRec);
        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewQuotes);
        lv1.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Logcat

```
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2191)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:675)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:639)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5128)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.widget.AbsListView$FlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:4188)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5155)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:756)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:572)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at miui.dexspy.DexspyInstaller.main(DexspyInstaller.java:171)
11-25 22:43:26.982: E/AndroidRuntime(17543):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)`
```

Comment: probably `c.getString` is returning null

Comment: are you create your `activity_customview` layout? Does it also have `R.id.tv` view?

Comment: yes <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fontFamily="Georgia"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dp" />